# Azure Database for PostgreSQL server backup before destroy

Tags: postgresql, azure, azure-postgresql

I currently have an Azure PostgreSQL server which I would like to permanently delete.

For obvious reasons I would like to make a snapshot/soft delete before turning off and deleting. What is the simplest way to accomplish this? I know there is a backup center option but I feel this is rather sophisticated for what I need.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can take the backup of Azure PostgreSQL server on the Azure Storage Account, then download the backup file locally from the storage account. After that you can delete the storage account and Azure PostgreSQL server.

Below is the article that shows how to take back up on Blob Storage.

[Backup Azure Database for PostgreSQL to a Blob Storage](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-database-for-postgresql/backup-azure-database-for-postgresql-to-a-blob-storage/ba-p/803343)